# Some doubts about Python function scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am absolutly new in Python and I have the following doubt related this simple code snippet:

```
def myFunction(myList1):
    print(myList1)
    myList1 = [0, 1]

def myFunction2(myList1):
    print(myList1)
    del myList1[0]

myList1 = [2, 3]
myFunction(myList1)
print(myList1)

myList2 = [2, 3]
myFunction2(myList2)
print(myList2)
```

As you can see I am defining **myFunction()** function that take a list as parameter. It change the values of the passed list. But since the parameter are passed by value and not by reference it have no effect outside the scope of this function. Infact when I print the **print(myList1)** value after the function invocation I still obtain the orginal values. This is pretty clear.

My doubt is related to the behavior of the **myFunction2()** function that take a list but change it deleting an item.

In this case when I print the content of the **myList2** list after the **myFunction2()** call I obtain that the orignal list was modified by the function?

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Everything is passed by reference in Python.  You are modifying the original list.

Comment: I added a metafora in my answer, which maybe will make it more clear to understand this problem

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister comment however, sums it all in brief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you passing it by reference, in both cases, but in the first function you changing the 'pointer' and the the value of it, `myList1 = [0, 1]` will not affect the original list because you changing the pointing of `myList1` into `[0,1]`, and at function2 you changing thing inside the list itself, you accessing a value in the list `myList1[0]`

Its the same as do:

```py
def f(l):
    l[0] = 2 # will change the list
    l = [1,2,3] # will change l in this scope to be equals to [1,2,3]
```

## Metafora

lets say you have a box, which calls `l`, and you pass the box to someone, lets say he calls Mr. Function, he can do whatever he want to the box, change the value of it (`l[0] = 2`), which will change the content of the box, but he can also replace the box itself (`l = [1,2,3]`), which not effect your box, notice the different between changing the content of my box, and replacing it.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `lists` are passed as `reference`. 
If you reassign a **label** inside a **method**, it will affect only the **local scope**, and that's something you already know.
Also, because `lists` are **mutable**, if you don't try to create a new `list` **object**, but modify the existing one, it will act just as expected, i.e. modifying the **reference** to the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Collections passed as arguments by reference.

When you call `myFunction`, the local variable (pointer) `myList1` refers to the same memory area as the global `myList1`.

If you change one - changes another.

But after `myList1 = [0, 1]` local `myList1` refers to a completely other instance of `list` and changing it will not affect the global `myList1`.